# Implicit template derivation for classes

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have this class:

```
template <typename T>
using VecBase = Eigen::MatrixBase<T>;

struct objective_QP 
{
private:
    const spMat Q;
    const spMat A;
    const Eigen::VectorXd b;
    const Eigen::VectorXd c;

public:

    template <typename V>
    objective_QP(const spMat& Q_, const VecBase<V> &c_): Q(Q_), c(c_)
    {}
    template <typename V>
    objective_QP(const spMat &Q_, const spMat& A_, const VecBase<V>& b_, const VecBase<V> &c_) : 
    Q(Q_), A(A_), b(b_), c(c_) {}


    template <typename V>
    inline scalar operator()(const VecBase<V> &x)
    {
        return (.5 * x.transpose() * Q * x + c.transpose() * x);
    }

    template <typename V>
    inline VecBase<V> Eval_grad(const VecBase<V> &x)
    {
        return Q.transpose() * x + c;
    }

    template <typename V>
    inline spMat Eval_hessian(const VecBase<V> &x)
    {
        return Q;
    }

    template <typename V>
    inline VecBase<V> Eval_c(const VecBase<V>& x)
    {
        return A*x-b;
    }

    template <typename V>
    inline spMat Eval_jac_c(const VecBase<V> & x)
    {        
        return A;
    }

};
```

When each method is templated inside the classes it compiles fine, and I'm able to construct objective_QP without specifying dimensions:

```
    objective_QP f(Q, c);
```

However, when I move the template specification outside the class:

```
template <typename V>
struct objective_QP
{
private:
const spMat Q;
const spMat A;
const VecBase<V> b;
etc..
```

It strictly requires type V to be specified, so I have to write:

```
objective_QP<V> f(Q, c);
```

It should be possible to derive V from constructor argument c. Is it possible to keep the implicit derivation and move the template specification outside the class?

Comment: Are you using C++17 (so with [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction))? What is `c`?

Comment: What are the types of `Q` and `c`? (I'm guessing you might need a template deduction guide.)

Comment: Q is an Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2>, c is an Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>.

Comment: I've followed the examples on implicit derivation given by eigen: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html

Comment: The posted code is not complete (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but as far as I can tell, the setup you are describing is the same as https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3G9GWvvT7, which works fine. Perhaps it's just a compiler flag issue (like @Jarod42 mentionned)

Answer (score 0):

Using C++17 instead of C++14 solved this issue, it seems like
Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD) as pointed out by Jarod42 is required for this.